# Encoding a URL in Java while leaving special characters untouched

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to construct a URL in Java, with the query parameters encoded.The encoder should escape the character '+'. All the methods that I've come across encode it. Is there any way I can accomplish this or do I need to write a custom encoder?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try "UriComponentsBuilder" if your using Spring.This package also contains other options that may fullfill your requirement.

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("URL String");
```

If your not using Spring can use "UrlValidator" given by "apache.commons"

```
String[] schemes = {"http","https"}; // DEFAULT schemes = "http", "https", "ftp"
        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
        if (urlValidator.isValid("urlString")) {
           System.out.println("URL is valid");
        } else {
           System.out.println("URL is invalid");
        }
```

Comment: Will it escape the '+' character?

Answer (score 0):

The `URI` class should be able to do this for you.  Specifically, use

```
URI​(String scheme, String userInfo, String host, 
    int port, String path, String query, String fragment)
```

or

```
URI​(String scheme, String authority, String path, String query, 
    String fragment)
```

to create the `URI` object, where the components that you provided are not encoded.  Then use `URI.toString()` or `URI.toASCIIString()` to produce the properly encoded URL.

---

> The encoder should escape the character '+'. All the methods that I've come across encode it.

Encoding the '+' as %2B% is the correct behavior.  The URL / URI specifications do not support escaping.  Any unencoded '+' in a URL will decode as a space character, no matter how you try to escape it.  That's what the spec says.

Comment: So, there's no way I can display a '+' in the address bar?

Comment: That depends on the implementation of the address bar; i.e. whether it automatically decodes the URL to display it.